# Construct custom json using Restkits RKObjectMapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, restkit

I'm trying to create a so called datastream via a RESTful API from my ios app using Restkit.
To do this, the API expects the following json POST:

```
{"version":"1.0.0",
  "datastreams" : [
    {
      "current_value" : "100",
      "id" : "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the API accepts an array of datastreams, but want I want to do is generate this json code from a single datastream object.

The datastream I want to create is represented in my application as an object with the following properties:

- version
- identifier
- currentValue

How should I set up the RKObjectMapping object so the code below constructs and send the above json to my API? (Asuming routes and all that other inital stuff has already been set)

```
Datastream *datastream = [[ZCCDatastream alloc] init];
datastream.version = @"1.0.0";
datastream.currentValue = @"100";
datastream.identifier = @"1";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:datastream delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a serialization mapping for Datastream. Try something like this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject: datastream usingBlock: ^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [Datastream class]];
    [mapping mapAttributes: @"version", nil];

    //etc.

    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.serializationMapping = mapping inverseMapping];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! In my code, I have one (1) Datastream object that I want to create, but the json API accepts an array of datastreams. The question is: what should I replace "etc." with in your code to construct the exact json structure that I posted? Is this even possible without creating a wrapper class with an array of datastreams?

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497335/how-to-serialize-a-flattened-object-back-to-server-unflattened-in-restkit) question